# How to find the current month and date in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel worksheet I have Month in column A and date in column B. I want a Excel macro if function to find if the month and date from current row matches to current (today's) date and month.
Below code is not giving any errors but not giving me any values either.

```
Sub CheckMatchAndHighlight()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentMonth As Integer
    Dim todayDate As Integer
    Dim matchFound As Boolean
    
    ' Set worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Find date match") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    
    ' Get current month and date
    currentMonth = Month(Date)
    todayDate = Day(Date)
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column A
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through rows
    For i = 2 To lastRow ' Assuming row 1 is header row
        ' Check if today's month and date match the values in columns A and B
        If Month(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value) = currentMonth And Day(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value) = todayDate Then
            ' Set match found flag
            matchFound = True
            ' Highlight the row
            ws.Rows(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) ' Yellow color
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Check if match is found
    If matchFound Then
        MsgBox "Match found!", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No match found!", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

I want know how to find current month and date.

Comment: Use month(date) or month(vba.date) to get current month

Comment: How are your variables declared and how do your dates look like in your sheet? I had my dates both as just dates entered and as string, my variables as Variant, Long and String and neither gave me an issue for your code. Also show the rest of your code since you're not getting any value?

Comment: If the value in `ws.Cells(i, 1).Value` is already a month number, doing `Month(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value)` will get *the month of the month*, so you are doing twice the same. In your post you said *I have Month in column A* so if you got just a month number it should be `If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = currentMonth`

Comment: @Notus_Panda I have updated the full code here. Also My sheet (name 'Find date match') have month (january, february, march, .... etc.) in coumn A and Dates (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9... etc ) in column B

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following then:

```
If Month("1 " & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value & " 2024") = currentMonth And Day(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value) = todayDate Then
        ' Set match found flag
        matchFound = True
```

This way, you build a long date like "1 March 2024" ([should be ok](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-convert-month-name-to-number-and-vice-versa/) in English, makes more sense in Dutch tbh)and it gets its Month number/value from there. Make sure it makes sense in your local settings, i.e. translate "march", etc. to your own language or you'll throw an error (at least I did in testing).